# Why CGBitmapInfo remove the kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault which in Objective-C?

Tags: swift, core-graphics

In Objective-C, the CGBitmapInfo contains:

```
kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask = 0x1F,
kCGBitmapFloatInfoMask = 0xF00,
kCGBitmapFloatComponents = (1 << 8),
kCGBitmapByteOrderMask     = kCGImageByteOrderMask,
kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault  = (0 << 12),
kCGBitmapByteOrder16Little = kCGImageByteOrder16Little,
kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little = kCGImageByteOrder32Little,
kCGBitmapByteOrder16Big    = kCGImageByteOrder16Big,
kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big    = kCGImageByteOrder32Big
```

However, in Swift 3.0, CGBitmapInfo removed the kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault:

```
public struct CGBitmapInfo : OptionSet {

    public init(rawValue: UInt32)
    public static var alphaInfoMask: CGBitmapInfo { get }
    public static var floatInfoMask: CGBitmapInfo { get }
    public static var floatComponents: CGBitmapInfo { get }
    public static var byteOrderMask: CGBitmapInfo { get }
    public static var byteOrder16Little: CGBitmapInfo { get }
    public static var byteOrder32Little: CGBitmapInfo { get }
    public static var byteOrder16Big: CGBitmapInfo { get }
    public static var byteOrder32Big: CGBitmapInfo { get }
}
```

That's why?

Can I init the `CGBitmapInfo` like `CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: 0)` to replace the `kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Can I init the `CGBitmapInfo` like `CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: 0)` to replace the `kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault`?***

The answer is YES.

Swift omits some 0-value enum label in some cases. (details depend on the version of Swift).

If you find some enum label is not imported into Swift, check the original source in Objective-C and confirm it really has integer value 0, then replace it with `init(rawValue: 0)`.

---

#### ADDED

I cannot have found much about ***That's why?***, only one you can find is in the [Xcode Release Notes (>Xcode 8.0>Swift)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW146):

> - The `None` members of imported `NS_OPTIONS` option sets are marked as unavailable when they are imported. Use `[]` to make an empty
>     option set, instead of a `None` member.

It is not clear enough what *`None` member* means, but it seems the designer of Swift importer prefers the empty set literal `[]` for `OptionSet` types when representing *default* or *none*.

So, the first half of this answer should be modified:

You can use `CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: 0)` to replace `kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault`, but the empty set literal is preferred:

```
let myBitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo = []
```

Comment: The feature seems not bad because `default` is ambiguous in some case.

Answer (score 1):

see CGBitmapInfo or CGImageByteOrderInfo https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgimagebyteorderinfo
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgbitmapinfo

As long as the 3 bits in the ByteOrderMask are 0, you are good. I have not found any doc stating what a byte order of 0 does. The following result in the same 0 value.

```
let b: CGBitmapInfo = []
let b = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: 0)
```

111000000000000 byteOrder mask

you can grab the possible values for ByteOrder from

```
001000000000000 == CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder16Little.rawValue 
010000000000000 == CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue 
011000000000000 == CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder16Big.rawValue 
100000000000000 == CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big.rawValue
```

example setting value

```
let b: CGBitmapInfo = [ .byteOrder32Big]
print("\(b.contains(.byteOrder32Big))") // true
print("\(b.contains(.byteOrder16Little))") // false
print("\(b.rawValue)") // 16384
```

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take a look at [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)